# Match all elements with punctuation mark except asterisk in r

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector **vec** which has elements with a punctuation mark in it. I want to return all elements with punctuation mark except the one with asterisk.

```
vec <- c("a,","abc","ef","abc-","abc|","abc*01")
> vec[grepl("[^*][[:punct:]]", vec)]
[1] "a,"     "abc-"   "abc|"   "abc*01"
```

why does it return "abc*01" if there is a negation mark[^*] for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try `grep` like below

```
grep("\\*",grep("[[:punct:]]",vec,value = TRUE), value = TRUE,invert = TRUE) # nested `grep`s for double filtering
```

or

```
grep("[^\\*[:^punct:]]",vec,perl = TRUE, value = TRUE) # but this will fail for case `abc*01|` (thanks for feedback from @Tim Biegeleisen)
```

which gives

```
[1] "a,"   "abc-" "abc|"
```

Comment: This logic _fails_ and passes the value `abc*01|`.  Your regex is saying to assert a non `*` punctuation character, but it does not eliminate strings having both `*` and non `*` punctuation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you again, now I see it. Do you have any tips on slightly modifying this regex? Would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated my answer with a "stupid" nested `grep`. Your further feedback is welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grepl` here:

```
vec <- c("a,","abc-","abc|","abc*01")
vec[grepl("^(?!.*\\*).*[[:punct:]].*$", vec, perl=TRUE)]

[1] "a,"   "abc-" "abc|"
```

The regex pattern used `^(?!.*\\*).*[[:punct:]].*$` will only match contents which does not contain any asterisk characters, while also containing at least one punctuation character:

```
^                from the start of the string
    (?!.*\*)     assert that no * occurs anywhere in the string
    .*           match any content
    [[:punct:]]  match any single punctuation character (but not *)
    .*           match any content
$                end of the string
```

Comment: Sorry for incomplete information but my vector also contains elements with no punctuation marks. I dont want them in my output. **I want only elements with punctuation except asterisk**

Comment: @DhwaniDholakia Then check the updated answer.  So if I understand correctly, the rule is, it must have punctuation, but it also must _not_ have `*`.  Is that right?

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen. Thanks a lot. I got my answer. I would be great if you can give information on the pattern you created.